# Inserting records in multiple tables using stored procedure in SQL Server database and ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to write a database application using SQL Server and ASP.NET.

I have three tables in my database:

```
Create Table PatientData
(
    PatientID int identity(1,1) Primary Key,
    Diagnosis varchar(max),
    Investigations varchar(max),
    Complications varchar(max),
    FollowUp varchar(max)
)

Create Table Surgeries
(
    SurgeryID int identity(1,1) Primary Key,
    PatientID int,
    SurgicalPrcedure varchar(max),
    SurgeryDate date,
    HospitalName varchar(max)
)

Create Table Media
(
    MediaID int idnetiy(1,1) Primary Key,
    PatientID int,
    MediaLink varchar(max)
)
```

Relationship between tables is like this: `PatientID` is FK in `Surgeries` and `Media` tables

I am storing media files in a project folder and path into database table.
I am using stored procedure to insert update and delete records from these tables.

Insert stored procedure is

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[SPInsertSVf6]
    @PatientID int Output,
    @PatientName varchar(max),
    @Diagnosis varchar(max),
    @Investigations varchar(max),
    @Complications varchar(max),
    @FollowUp varchar(max),
    @SurgeryDate date,
    @SurgicalProcedure varchar(max),
    @HospitalName varchar(max),
    @MediaLink varchar(max)
As
Begin
    Set NoCount On

    Insert Into PatientData (PatientName, Diagnosis, Investigations, Complications, FollowUp) 
    Values (@PatientName, @Diagnosis, @Investigations, @Complications, @FollowUp)

    Set @PatientID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    Insert Into Surgeries (PatientID, SurgeryDate, SurgicalProcedure, HospitalName)
    Values (@PatientID, @SurgeryDate, @SurgicalProcedure, @HospitalName)

    Insert Into Media (PatientID, MediaLink) 
    Values (@PatientID, @MediaLink)
End
```

and my C# code is

```
namespace MultipleImages
{
    public partial class WebForm6 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=QUANTUM\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SurgicalVideos;Integrated Security=True");
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Img = "";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SPInsertSVf6", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PatientID", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "PatientID");
            cmd.Parameters["@PatientID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PatientName", TextBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Diagnosis", TextBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Investigations", TextBox3.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Complications", TextBox4.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FollowUp", TextBox5.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SurgeryDate", TextBox6.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SurgicalProcedure", TextBox7.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("HospitalName", TextBox8.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MediaLink", FileUpload1.FileName);

            foreach (HttpPostedFile hpf in FileUpload1.PostedFiles) 
            {
                if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    Img = Convert.ToString(hpf);
                    Img = "Images/" + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName);
                    hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
                    Label3.Text += String.Format("{0}<br />", hpf.FileName);
                }
            }

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is this code insert all media in project folder but only first record in database. I will be very grateful if someone please help me write the correct code to insert all records in the `Media` table.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the value in your FileUpload1.FileName ? Seems you are only sending one string to your stored procedure and saving it into 1 record. Hint: you will either need to do an insert in your foreach in C# or do a split of the values of @MediaLink in you stored procedure and do an insert for each.

Comment: You should be constructing the `SqlCommand` and executing it **inside the `foreach`**.

Comment: Not sure if this is just an example.  I would suggest taking a look at this:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524900(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 0):

you are saving files in foreach so all of them will save
but you are executing sql command out of foreach so it will execute just one time
you should fill store procedure parameters in forech and execute it in foreach to unless it will save last record

just open and close connection can be out of foreach area

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but when I put the code block within foreach loop, it gives error cannot convert type char to System.Web.HttpPostedFile